# Infinitely many $f$-invariant subspaces iff $f^2=0$ for $f$ a nilpotent endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, nilpotence

Let $f$ be a nilpotent endomorphism of a 3 dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$. My book says that $f$ has infinitely many $f$-invariant subspaces if and only if $f^2=0$, but it does not show me why.

Can somebody prove this for me, since it doesn't seem that trivial to me and I have no clue as to why this would hold?

Edit: Can you prove this without using Jordan forms?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f$ is a nilpotent endomorphism of a $3$-dimensional vector space.  Then its only eigenvalue is $0$, and the three possible Jordan forms of $f$ are
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\&0&1\\&&0}, \quad
\pmatrix{0\\&0&1\\&&0},\quad
\pmatrix{0\\&0\\&&0}
$$
The form satisfying $J^2 \neq 0$ does *not* have infinitely many invariant subspaces, since it only has a one-dimensional eigen-space.  The other two forms have an eigenspace of dimension $2$, and therefore have infinitely may $1$-dimensional eigenspaces.

---

**Without Jordan canonical form:**

Suppose that $f$ is a nilpotent endomorphism of a $3$-dimensional vector space.  Then, its only eigenvalue is $0$.

Suppose that there is a $v$ such that $f^2(v) \neq 0$.  Show, then, that $f$ has the form
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\&0&1\\&&0}
$$
With respect to the basis $\{f^2(v),f(v),v\}$.  If $f$ has no such vector, show that it must map a two-dimensional eigenspace to $0$.

Comment: Is there a way of proving this without using Jordan forms? I havent studied those yet.

Comment: Have you studied minimal polynomials?  Characteristic polynomials? Eigenvalues, in some capacity?

Comment: All of the above, just not yet Jordan forms. We're working our way to those now, but still not there yet. That's why I would really appreciate it if you could show me a proof without using Jordan.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but how do I show that if there are infinitely many $f$-invariant subspaces it means that $f^2=0$?

Comment: @Barry_Allen If $f^2(v) \neq 0$ for some $v$, the without-Jordan-canonical-form argument shows that $f$ can be written in a particular form in an adapted basis, but this transformation does not have infinitely many $f$-invariant subspaces. Contrapositively, if $f$ does have infinitely many such subspaces, we must have $f^2(v) = 0$ for all $v$, i.e., that $f^2 = 0$.

Comment: @Barry_Allen the idea is to show that $f^2 = 0 \iff f$ has a two-dimensional eigenspace.